# Thread id not showing in logs

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j, jms

My applications listens to messages on a queue and then publishes results to Tibco subject. We have written a message listener which is called via "onMessage" method of "MessageListener"

Problem i am facing is that all the threads in logs show same thread name i.e. `"TIBCO EMS Session Dispatcher (21367271)"`. And its making it very difficult to track which thread is doing what.

My log4j expression is `"%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{1} [%t] - %m%n"` .

What change do i need to make to get proper thread id?

EDIT:

I want to be able to differentiate between log messages printed for processing of different messages. At present i can't do that with thread name.

Comment: That is the correct pattern label. Are there many threads going through the code that logs whatever message it is you are logging?

Comment: What makes you think that that is not the executing thread's name?

Comment: I receive multiple messages in my queue which would mean multiple threads will be doing the processing. Now i need to way to differentiate the logs printed by these multiple threads. At present i can't differentiate. Does that explain the problem?

Comment: Have you named all your threads the same?

Comment: Are you sure they're not dealt with _serially_ with a single dispatch thread? (I only ask since I would have imagined Tibco would have set them to a useful identifier).

Comment: @Greg: Its not a single thread, multiple threads with same name are getting created.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I am not naming any threads at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to set the name of the thread as you like.  You could do:

```
private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

public void onMessage(Message message)
{
  String oldName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
  Thread.currentThread.setName("my-thread-" + count.getAndIncrement())

  try
  {
    // ... existing code ...
  }
  finally
  {
    Thread.currentThread().setName(oldName);
  }
}
```

An alternate to the atomic integer for uniquely identifying the thread would be to use the identity hash code:

```
Thread.currentThread.setName("my-thread-" + System.identityHashCode());
```